# Calculating the next run time for the task

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have the following data-structure for the task:

```
Task{
    Start: 17:00:00
    End:   20:00:00
    Interval: 5
    Days: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
}
```

So this is something like a schedule setting for some task. I have a windows service that ticks each 5 seconds and does some calculations if it is time to run the task. It quite simple to check that. For example I am checking if the day of the current time is in `Days` array, if the current time is between `Start` and `End` etc. So this task will execute at `17:05:04`, `17:10:01` etc(approximation is 5 seconds). So it the current time is close to `17:00 + N*5 seconds` it executes some code. That is working properly.

I am struggling now with figuring out with a calculations for the time when this task will be executed in the future. If for example now is `Monday 16:58:30` the next time it will be executed is `Monday 17:05`. If it is `Friday 18:00` it will be executed at `Saturday 17:05`. If it is `Monday 18:33` the next run is `Monday 18:35`. The difficulties come when you realize that Start can be something like Start: `17:03:00` and so running times are shifted now `17:08`, `17:13` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the next run for the task.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="task"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetNextRun(TaskBase task)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var currentDay = now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7.ToString() : ((int)now.DayOfWeek).ToString();
    var currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;

    var startAt = task.StartAt;

    //If Days is empty the task will never execute.
    if (task.Days.Length == 0)
    {
        return "Never";
    }
    //If the current day is allowed.
    else if (task.Days.Contains(currentDay))
    {
        //If current time is allowed
        if (currentTime >= task.StartAt && currentTime <= task.StopAt)
        {
            //Start from beginning and add interval till we get a time greater than current day.
            while (startAt < currentTime)
            {
                startAt = startAt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(task.IntervalInMinutes));
            }

            //If we are still in the allowed range return this time.
            if (startAt >= task.StartAt && startAt <= task.StopAt)
            {
                return now.Date.Add(startAt).ToString();
            }
        }
        //If we are before starting point just return the first tick.
        else if (currentTime < task.StartAt)
        {
            startAt = startAt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(task.IntervalInMinutes));

            return now.Date.Add(startAt).ToString();
        }
    }

    startAt = task.StartAt;

    //If the current day is not allowed or the day is allowed but currentTime > task.StopAt.
    //Add days until we get next allowed day and return the first tick.
    while (true)
    {
        now = now.AddDays(1);
        currentDay = now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7.ToString() : ((int)now.DayOfWeek).ToString();

        if (task.Days.Contains(currentDay))
        {
            startAt = startAt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(task.IntervalInMinutes));

            return now.Date.Add(startAt).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```